# How to limit the floating point decimal while using describe function on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I get the below output on running `df['CodingHours'].describe()`.

1. Is there a way to round this up to a few decimal places?
2. Also, why is the standard deviation not exactly 1, can someone help me understand this?

```
count    1.000000e+02
mean    -2.220446e-17
std      1.005038e+00
min     -2.056291e+00
25%     -9.160188e-01
50%      2.242536e-01
75%      6.043443e-01
max      1.364526e+00
Name: CodingHours, dtype: float64
```

Comment: For rounding up, use: `df['CodingHours'].describe().round(1)`. For `std`, please share your `df`. It's hard to say otherwise.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thank You !!! 

`std_scaler=StandardScaler()
df3['CodingHours']=std_scaler.fit_transform(df3[['CodingHours']])
`

I have used a **Standard Scaler** from sklearn to transform the given dataset to Standard Scale. I was expecting it to be exactly 1.

Answer (score 2):

You may add `.round(3)` ad the end of your command.

Try below command:
`df['CodingHours'].describe().round(3)`

Comment: Thank You !!! 
`std_scaler=StandardScaler() df3['CodingHours']=std_scaler.fit_transform(df3[['CodingHours']])`  I have used a Standard Scaler from sklearn to transform the given dataset to Standard Scale. I was expecting it to be exactly 1.